# From array to two new arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, copy

How can I copy the found value (+ rest data of the row) to two new arrays?
In `minmaxarray` is column 0 time and column 1 value.
Loop until it finds a negative value -> found `minpeak`.
When `minpeak` is found, that row + the first positive value found -> (`maxpeak`) row
will be copied to `minpeaks` array and `maxpeaks` array.

```
maxpeaks=[]
minpeaks=[]
for m in minmaxarray[:,1]:
    if m < 0:
        maxpeak = minmaxarray[m-1,:]
        maxpeaks.append(maxpeak)
        minpeak = minmaxarray[m,:]
        minpeaks.append(minpeak)
```

Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: What's the exception your code is throwing?

Comment: `[:,1]` isn't valid array slice syntax. I am guessing that should be `[:1]`? (or `[::1]`, but that's the same as no slicing at all).

Comment: @Zinki: it works for `numpy` arrays.

Comment: @toti08 granted, but we don't know what `minmaxarray` is, and both `maxpeaks` and `minpeaks` are lists, so the syntax won't work there.

Comment: @Zinki true, indeed I think this answer needs more clarification, like a sample input and the error thrown (if any)...

Comment: @Ianneke113 I still don't get what's wrong with your code, sorry!

Comment: @toti08 it's ok, I solved it myself for now :) Thanks for thinking with me!

Answer (score 0):

The code that works for me now:

```
maxpeaks=[]
minpeaks=[]
for id, m in enumerate(minmaxarray[:,1]):
    if m < 0:
        maxpeak = minmaxarray[id+1,:]
        minpeak = minmaxarray[id,:]
        minpeaks.append(minpeak)
minpeaks = np.array(minpeaks)
maxpeaks = np.array(maxpeaks)
```